# Gstreamer subtitles while recording

Tags: gstreamer, subtitle, transport-stream

I am new to GStreamer and am trying to encode a video stream (for now v4l2src) with a subtitle stream and muxed into an MPEG ts container. I am able to use 'textoverlay' to set the data but I don't want to burn the data into the image. However I am wanting to use the subtitle stream to encode 'metadata' that is generated while the video is being recorded.

Is there a way that I can add subtitles into the MPEG ts as time passes? The content of the subtitle text is not known before hand, for example the gps coords of a moving camera.

There is the 'subtitleoverlay' plugin but I do not fully understand this one. Does it burn the text into the image like the 'textoverlay' or does it add a separate stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that subtitleoverlay renders and burn text into video frames.. check the [example pipeline](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-subtitleoverlay.html) there is no magic - after subtitle overlay there is videoconvert which works with video frames..

I guess you can just attach subtitle stream into mpegtsmux element. I hope this is [possible now](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Mpegtsmux-subtitles-td4525966.html) - there is [this bug/feature request](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=673582) which I hope makes this possible..

I checked the capabilities of mpegtsmux and it supports:

> subpicture/x-dvb
>
> application/x-teletext

If you can somehow manage to input subtitles in form of subpicture/x-dvb then later on receiver you can use dvbsuboverlay element to display them..
I didnt find a way how you can actualy create such stream from text file(I found [this](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/rendering-subpicture-x-dvb-from-ass-pango-txt-subtitles-td4667354.html) question but no answer, maybe ask on IRC)..

I have a feeling that teletext was capable of showing subtitles.. but this may not be what you want (I dont know)..

In both cases I think that if you had rendered stream with rendered subtitles (only subtitles) in form of subtitles.mpg you could use that.. I guess there are some tools out there in wild that you can use for that..

Hope you can use that somehow